# HUD post-processing in Godot

Tags: godot, post-processing, hud, godot-shader-language

I have a project in Godot that renders billboarded quads on top of enemies. The quads(meshinstances) are children nodes of the enemy nodes. I want to render just the quads to a viewport for post-processing, but the quads need to have the same position on screen that the enemies have (like a target reticle).
How can I apply a shader effect to the billboards only and not to the rest of the scene?

Comment: It might be possible to put the HUD elements in a separate tree and use [`RemoteTransform`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_remotetransform.html) to keep them in the right place. Render the HUD tree to a texture and apply it to a Viewport so you can add your own custom postprocessing shader.

Answer (score 2):

The `Camera` has a `cull_mask` property that lets you filter which layers it will see. And `VisualInstance`s (such as `MeshInstance`s) have a `layers` property that lets you specify to which layers they belong (by default they all belong to the first layer).

You can configure the layers names in Project Settings -> General -> Layer Names -> 3d Render. *Do not confuse them with 3d Physics.*

Thus, you can give a different layer to those quad `MeshInstance` you want, and then setup a new `Viewport` with a new `Camera` as child (make sure it is `current`) with a `cull_mask` that will only render that layer. That way only those `MeshInstance` will be rendered on that `Viewport`.

*You probably want to to keep the properties of the `Camera` in sync with the `Camera` on main `Viewport` (not only its `global_transform`, but also `fov` or any other property you might change). You can archive this by copying its properties on `_process` of a script attached to the `Camera` which is inside the new `Viewport`.*