# Is it possible to add fragments outside of a 3D model's area?

Tags: glsl, godot, godot-shader-language

In a 3D scene in Godot, I am attempting to create a pixel-perfect outline for a Spatial shader (applied after a pixelation effect to ensure the same resolution). To achieve this, I would like to modify pixels *directly adjacent* to the target mesh.

That said, I have a hunch that I simply cannot modify pixels outside of a mesh's area in screespace, and that I would have to use a separate donor mesh to achieve this effect. The issue with this is that I'm even more unsure of how to access an external mesh (I am fine applying the same pixel perfect effect to all meshes on-screen, but it would have to be pixel-perfect).

A secondary solution that I may have to settle with: do an inwards bleed for the outline, sacrificing the outermost pixels for the outline, which would be acceptable compromise.

Comment: You could do it as a postprocessing effect, working entirely on screen-space pixels. Write some flag value to a buffer for each pixel occupied by the mesh, then check all four (or eight) adjacent pixels in your postprocessing shader. If the current pixel is not flagged but a neighbour is, then it's part of the outline. (This is just a sketch of a solution; I can't help you implement this in Godot.)

Comment: It's a good idea, although it would depend on whether I can set external values from the shader code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can render just the elements you want to a `Viewport` using `cull_mask` as I just described in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72421363/402022).

Now, you can take the texture from that `Viewport` use a `ViewportTexture` (make sure it is local to the scene and you are using it a `Node` placed after the `Viewport` in the scene tree) and process it using a shader.

I suggest you make the background of the `Viewport` transparent, so you can use the alpha channel to check if a pixel is rendered or not. The outline pixels will be those which are not rendered but are adjacent to a pixel that was rendered.

*This is the idea behind convolution edge detection. See [Kernel (image processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)).*

Comment: Detecting where the outline is to be placed is not an issue for me, but *rendering* it so that it outlines an arbitrary `MeshInstance` (in my case, it will be used for characters and some scenery). Now I assume the need to to use a `ViewportTexture` is due to the different functionality of `CanvasItem` shaders.

A solution to implementing this would be to cull the player from the game camera and replace their image with the `ViewportTexture`. Assuming the image is pulled from the game camera's perspective, it should be identical to what the `MeshInstance` would look like.

Comment: For bonus points, the original mesh could cast shadows while being otherwise invisible to leverage its unique 3D properties.